# What terminology is used to distinguish between these different types of measurements of running time

Tags: performance, time, big-o, time-complexity

I see 3 cases for what running time could mean.

1. Big O notation, i.e the running time is O of n^2.
2. Time in basic operations, i.e the running time is 2n or 56
3. Time in milliseconds or seconds, i.e. the running time is 5.42ms or 3s.

What terminology can be used to distinguish between these three things? It's confusing when you have a conversation about running time, and you're referring to one of these and the other person is thinking you're referring to another.

Are they all actually called running time?

Comment: I believe the first one can be considered as algorithmic efficiency and the third one is CPU time.

Comment: **The first one**, it tells a very theoretic/general behavior of your algorithm. **The second one**, it allows you to obtain exactly the number of iterations, recursive calls, or even instructions: sometimes, you may have two different algorithms destined to yield the same result, with the same order of growth, but one does a fewer operations than the other. **The third one**, generally Computer Scientists/Operating Systems leaned profiles have this sensibility (knowing CPU speed and other details).

Comment: the first one is not runtime at all (it is limit n -> +inf of runtime which for not inf n often get very different values from runtime) the second one is sometimes written like this T(2n) or T(56) ... also have sometimes seen o(2n) but that is really confusing. 2 is usually used if you do not measure actual time but derive the operation count directly from program source (or count them inside by some counter) 3. is direct measurement of runtime either of the whole thing or just critical parts of program so you see what part is the bottleneck.